# Intent With Extras

Tags: java, android

I have an upload activity that can result to 3 options.
Result 1: Successful Upload of data.
Result 2: Upload not Successful.

Previous Activity Code

```
protected void onPostExecute(String string1) {
super.onPostExecute(string1);
progressDialog.dismiss();
final Intent intent = new Intent(UploadActivity.this, SuccessActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("VAL1", string1);
startActivity(intent);
 } 
catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Mysql Results code

```
if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
       //Data To Be Uploaded.........
        echo "Your Data Was Successfully Uploaded. Thank You";
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
}else{ }
```

ResultsActivity Android

```
public class SuccessActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView textView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.success_main);

Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
String data = null;
String data2 = "Your Data Upload Was NOT Successfull!!";

if (getIntent()!= null && getIntent().getExtras() != null) {

       if (extras.getString("val1") != null) {
                data = extras.getString("val1");
                textView = findViewById(R.id.experiences);
                textView.setText(data);
            }
       else if(getIntent() != null && getIntent().getExtras() == null) {
                textView = findViewById(R.id.experiences);
                textView.setText(data2);
            }
       else if (getIntent() == null && getIntent().getExtras() == null){
                textView = findViewById(R.id.experiences);
                textView.setText(data2);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where are the putExtra()'s?

Comment: You should not let this activity decide if an upload is succes full or not but send it the right message with putExtra like `putExtra("Data Upload Not Successfull!!");` or what ever.

Comment: `If(extras.hasKey("val1")) //success expression `

Comment: I have edited the code to suggest what i need

Comment: Why are you calling `getIntent()` so many times instead of variable `intent` that you have already declared.

Comment: @pratik butani. I hear you. Do you get what I want to achieve first?

Comment: Where you have called `putExtra`?

Comment: @NyP what is it that you require, or are trying to achieve?

Comment: @electrocrat
I have an upload activity with two results returned by the server.

Result 1: Data Upload Successful. Result 2: Upload Not Successful.

I added a third result of intent not being received (e.g device data off, or device has no data bundles). How can i return these and set textviews to a message of these depending on what was returned?

Comment: So the `UploadActivity` launches the above `SuccessActivity` to display the result. Your code is a bit redundant but it should work fine. Unless as others have stated that the `putExtra` from the `UploadActivity` is not working. So share that code too.

Comment: @electrocrat see my edited quiz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to this:
[How do I get extra data from intent on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-do-i-get-extra-data-from-intent-on-android)

Your extra String "VAL1" is not in a Bundle.

Change your `SuccessActivity` code to this and try:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.success_main);

    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.experiences);

    String dataerror = "Your Data Upload Was NOT Successfull!!";

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent != null) {
        String data = intent.getStringExtra("VAL1"); //  Thats the right way to get the extra String;
        if(data != null && !data.isEmpty()) {
            textView.setText(data);
        } else {
            textView.setText(dataerror);
        }
    } else {
        textView.setText(dataerror);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the efforts but its not working. When i put data off before upload or rename the upload script in the server the textview is still empty instead of outputting the Not Successful Message

Comment: Is `SuccessActivity` opening up?

Comment: Yes it is opening but has empty textview instead of outputting the Not Successful Message. For successful upload it is ok just like it was doing in the initial code

Comment: Maybe the String result is empty?
Try adding a `&& !data.isEmpty()` to that `if(data != null)` check.

Comment: String data = intent.getStringExtra("VAL1"); was to return the success message any other condition to return dataerror message in your code above. Can we try a code for null intent?

Comment: Yes, the first check is to see if `intent = null`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209098/discussion-between-electrocrat-and-nyp).