# Android-I tried sending data from one activity to another using intents

Tags: android

In this app, I want to test how to send data between `activities`. This is the code that I used:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText parola,email;
    Button buton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        parola.findViewById(R.id.enterPassword);
        email.findViewById(R.id.enterMail);
        buton.findViewById(R.id.button);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String StrEmail=email.getText().toString();
        String StrParola=parola.getText().toString();
        buton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityB.class);
                i.putExtra("mail",StrEmail);
                i.putExtra("pass",StrParola);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But every time I open the app, it just crashes.

Comment: you should get the editText input texts after the user clicks the button, initially, those are empty. put them inside onClick. paste your error log also.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get extra data from intent on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-do-i-get-extra-data-from-intent-on-android)

Comment: there seems to be an error in findViewById()..... it should be parola=findViewById(R.id.enterPassword); change similarly for email and button.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `=` before intiliasing the `Editext` and `Button`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText parola,email;
Button buton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

    parola = findViewById(R.id.enterPassword); // forgot =
    email = findViewById(R.id.enterMail);
    buton = findViewById(R.id.button);

    String StrEmail=email.getText().toString();
    String StrParola=parola.getText().toString();
    buton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityB.class);
            i.putExtra("mail",StrEmail);
            i.putExtra("pass",StrParola);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: He was trying to initialize them using a dot ```email.findBiewById()```. Also he was doing it BEFORE the setContentView().