# Activity struck while pressing back key

Tags: android, android-activity, listactivity

There is no action performed on the activity when i press back key till some time. No code return to handle back key in my activity. I am starting a activity when user clicks on list item. Like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(cxt, MyActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Actual thing hapening is,when user clicks instantly thrice,My activity is launched multiple times.How can i avoid launch activity more than once.
I can not use single instance/singleton because my `OnCreate` should be called every time the  activity is launched.

Comment: Isn't setting a flag easiest?

Comment: there are many things happening in onclick based on conditions,keeping flag's could mess my code

Comment: Decide wether you start an activity or not outside the activity, and consider checking conditions there. You can pass results to your new intent based on the conditions.

Comment: Thanks for new point.How can i pass result in intent based on conditions.Please get me out of it

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that you do extensive processing in one of the Activity lifecycle callbacks which Android calls in this case to destroy your Activity.

Comment: I agree, but i am cleaning when closing.The point is how can i avoid launching activity multiple times. ? when i m launching activity multiple times oncreate is called twice.No point of talking about onDestroy or any other callback

Comment: @421 You should disable the event handling activity once the list entry is pressed once. However, it sounds like your app needs some redesign there -- you don't do extensive computing on the main UI thread, period. Show a "please be patient" box and perform your computations concurrently, I'd say?

Comment: i am not not passing huge data thru intent.I am performing extensive operations in onResume();In this context talking about onResume has no point.While starting activity, activity starts quickly as usual,thing is when user pressing the list item with huge frequency, multiple activites are getting launched.How avoid this.

Comment: @421 As I said, you avoid this by disabling the event handling activity (probably for the whole list at once). So, if you have the same event listener for all list entries, you'll have a flag that indicates that an entry has been "clicked" on and processing is not yet done. Or, if such a "click" leads to a different activity being displayed anyway, just disable the event listener for once and all (in this instance of your activity). If you have several event listeners, the question is whether your user should still be allowed to "click" on another list entry.

Answer (score 0):

Decide wether you start an activity or not outside the activity itself, and consider checking conditions there. You can pass parameters to your new intent based on the conditions.

here is a question on that topic: [How to start an Intent by passing some parameters to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405120/how-to-start-an-intent-by-passing-some-parameters-to-it)

Answer (score -1):

you can still use singleInstance and override onNewIntent method which will be called on every relaunch of activity , or separate expensive operations in handler post methods  .